# AngularJS Sample Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning `AngularJS` and can't get a simple code to work. Here are my codes:

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
   <head>
      <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0-alpha.31" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body ng-controller="MainController">
      <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var MainController = function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Test message";
};
```

When I run the code, I always get `{{ message }}` instead of the `Test message`. Am I missing something? Thank you.

Comment: It probably won't be relevant to the solution, but you should be careful with `data-semver="2.0.0-alpha.31"`,  Angular 1.4.5 and the Angular2 Alphas are not compatible, Angular2 is a complete framework rewrite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0-alpha.31" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var app=angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("MainController",function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Test message";
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure, to define a controller with function not variables ( [read more](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)

Here is a working exemple :

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', []);

angular
  .module('myApp')
  .controller('MainController', MainController);

function MainController($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Test message";
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```